# Laravel Cashier Product Description Stripe Invoice

Tags: laravel, invoice, stripe-payments

I have a question about Stripe invoices. I want to change some text from stripe invoice. You can see on the image with blue underline or blue arrow.I use laravel cashier and want when create subscription to add additional information to the invoice. [ImageLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRxtH.png)

Comment: Where are you seeing that text? It doesn't look like the invoice pages I am seeing. For subscription invoices, you cannot update the automatically-generated invoice items. You can only add items to the draft invoice. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#adding-draft-invoice-items

Comment: That text is driven by your plan/product names, so you'd need to modify those to change the text used.

Comment: thanks for the information, I will create plans with products inside with correct description adn will use them